# Get access to other view in fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with setting the visibility of an TextView.

I have two xmls. One for the fragment itself and the other for the RecyclerView.
In the fragment_settings.xml I'm setting the RecyclerView. In the settings_list_row.xml I define the RecyclerView row.

When I create a new RecyclerView row I sometimes have a row where twice of the TextView's are filled and sometimes just one. Because of this I want to set the visibility of one TextView to gone if it's empty.

Because my View is the fragment_settings.xml I don't have access to the row view. Is there a solution for this? Thanks a lot!

### fragment_settings.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="de.myfitindustry.myfitindustry.app.SettingsFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/accountTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/accountTitle" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/settings_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### settings_list_row.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingSubtitle"
        android:layout_below="@id/settingTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Fragments `onCreateView` method

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view  =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.settings_recycler_view);
        sAdapter = new SettingsAdapter(settingList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager sLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()) {
            // Disable scrolling in the RecyclerView
            @Override
            public boolean canScrollVertically() {
                return false;
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(sLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        prepareSettingsData();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(sAdapter);


        // HERE I WANT TO CHANGE THE VISIBILITY
        TextView settingSubtitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.settingSubtitle);

        if(!settingSubtitle.getText().equals("")) {
            settingSubtitle.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

### My RecyclerView Adapter:

```
package de.myfirstapp.app;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Johannes on 19.01.2017.
 */

public class SettingsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SettingsAdapter.MySettingHolder> {

    private List<Settings> settingList;

    public class MySettingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView settingTitle, settingSubtitle;

        public MySettingHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            settingTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.settingTitle);
            settingSubtitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.settingSubtitle);
        }
    }

    public SettingsAdapter (List<Settings> settingList) {
        this.settingList = settingList;
    }

    @Override
    public MySettingHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.settings_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MySettingHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MySettingHolder holder, int position) {
        // Setting for one entry
        Settings setting = settingList.get(position);
        holder.settingTitle.setText(setting.getSettingTitle());
        holder.settingSubtitle.setText(setting.getSettingSubtitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return settingList.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: it's pretty simple, just go to ur onBindViewHolder(){...} method of recycler adapter and put a condition,    if(! (TextView)holder.settingSubtitle.getText().equals("")) {
            (TextView)holder.settingSubtitle.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
        }

Comment: Not very clear about the question.But if you want access to the recycler view's row, you have to use onBindViewHolder() method of the adapter and set the visibility accordingly.

Comment: @AninditaPani You have understand it :) I always try my best to write my question as good as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't do it in `SettingsAdapter` `onBindViewHolder` method? Imagine, you have bunch of items in your `RecyclerView` and bunch of `settingSubtitle`, how system will understand which `TextView` do you really want?

### Update

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MySettingHolder holder, int position) {
        // Setting for one entry
        Settings setting = settingList.get(position);

        if (setting.getSettingSubtitle().equals("")) {
            holder.settingTitle.setText(setting.getSettingTitle());
            holder.settingSubtitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.settingSubtitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.settingTitle.setText(setting.getSettingTitle());
            holder.settingSubtitle.setText(setting.getSettingSubtitle());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm a beginner with Android and I don't know how to do a lot of things :/ and there are a lot of problems where I can't find an answer with google. How can I do this in my adapter?

Comment: Paste your RecyclerView.Adapter class and i'll help you

Comment: The point is that I want to remove the whole TextView and not the entry because of formation

Comment: Oh my friend ^-^ it works so great. Edited your question a little bit :)

Comment: By the way can I set margin in this if statement too? Because it don't fit in my layout anymore? If just the settingTitle is visible is should get a marginTop and bottom 18dp. If the else is true the settingTitle should get marginTop 18 and bottom 0 and the settingSubtitle marginTop 0 and bottom 18

Comment: @ItsOdi1 yes, you can set what ever you want. But be sure to set both values (if true or not) because RecyclerView doesn't create view, it just uses unused one (recycles them), and if you'll set margin once, all views that will be recycled from it will be with this margin

Comment: I've tried it with a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams object and set rlp.setMargins(0, 18, 0, 18); in my if statement and holder.settingTitle.setLayoutParams(rlp); to my TextView but no effect

Comment: @ItsOdi1 try to set settingTitle layot_width to "wrap_content" instead of "match_parent"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133560/discussion-between-itsodi1-and-ekalips).